# Did Shiva kill Yama? If so, then who does the work of Yama now?

Tags: shiva, death, yama

> The wrathful Yama assumed a fearsome form and threw his noose to capture Markandeya, who hugged the linga tightly. When the noose touched the linga, Shiva emerged from it in all his wrath and struck Yama with his Trishula and kicked his chest, killing the Lord of Death.

as given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalantaka#Legend_and_its_message.

Comment: the same page that you linked says in next paragraph: "The Earth, the gods, and Markandeya invoked Shiva to revive Yama. Once again, Shiva touched Yama with his foot, bringing him back to life." :)